# Transfer from one Amazon RDS to another account's amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a ~200gb rds I need to transfer over to a new account (cannot avoid this)

Is there a straightforward way of doing this transfer?

Amazon's docs seem to suggest something to the end of

```
mysqldump –h RDS instance endpoint -u user –p password --port 3306 --single-transaction --routines --triggers --databases database database2 --compress --compact | -h New MySQL host -u master user -p password --port 3306
```

I have worries that that will work, esp when it comes to the size I am dealing with.

Comment: Is the database running a live system, or can the application be taken offline for the migration?  Related also, which major.minor.version of MySQL are you running on the rds instances?

Comment: I can take if offline/use a diff server if neccesary. mysql 5.5.27